# How to get serverTimestamp via Angularfire or firebase

Tags: angular, angularfire2

**I can't find a way to get serverTimestamp from firestore.** Either with firestore itself, or with angularfire.

I found a lot of github issues with solutions, which doesn't work. I guess that's because of a different version?

```
"@firebase/app": "^0.1.10",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0",
"firebase": "^4.13.1",
```

**Code alternatives I've tried:**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'FieldValue' of undefined

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ServerValue' of undefined

```
constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore ) { }
this.afs.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

> Property 'FieldValue' does not exist on type 'FirebaseFirestore'.

Comment: How does it work with firebase 9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What helped at the end was uninstalling everything firebase related, so as I mentioned in my question:

```
"@firebase/app": "^0.1.10",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0",
"firebase": "^4.13.1",
```

And running `npm install firebase angularfire2 --save` again.

This gave me:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7",
"firebase": "^5.0.1",
```

Which fixed all my problems.

Import firebase as:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

The timestamp code itself:

```
get timestamp() {
  return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```

EDIT on 17th november:
If you'll use the previously mentioned import `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`, you'll get this warning in developer console:

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS
>   SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to
>   only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
>
> For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
>   (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database,
>   etc):
>
> CommonJS Modules: const firebase = require('firebase/app');
>   require('firebase/');
>
> ES Modules: import firebase from 'firebase/app'; import
>   'firebase/';
>
> Typescript: import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'; import
>   'firebase/';

So change it to:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Comment: how do you import `firebase`?

Comment: createdAt
_methodName: 
"FieldValue.serverTimestamp"

Comment: it created above data not time stamp

Comment: @Midhilaj you maybe use JSON.stringify when pushing new item on collection, and it's why you obtain a map record `_methodName: "FieldValue.serverTimestamp`. If you do replace it with spread operator: `afs.collection<Item>('items').add({...item)`

Answer (score 9):

Doing just:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Imports all of firebase modules which is not a good practice for production. 
The best practice  is to use bare imports like so:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'; 
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

This will only import Firestore module in your app.  You can then do:

```
get timestamp() {
return firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
};
```

Comment: createdAt
_methodName: 
"FieldValue.serverTimestamp"

Comment: it created above data not timestamp

Comment: @Midhilaj, my answer is on the best way to import the firestore library to avoid importing the whole firebase in your code. Did you read through  the answer before down-voting?

Answer (score 7):

Since firebase 8.0.0, there is a breaking change on how to import firebase [Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_800_-_october_26_2020)

Before you would import with

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

But now, you should import with

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

You then should still import only firestore to access the servertimestamp

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
```

and in your app use

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Comment: The latest version of AngularFire (Firebase 9+, AngularFire 7+) has further breaking changes due to a redesign for reducing the bundle size. The current recommendation from the Firebase team is to use compatibility mode by changing your imports to 'firebase/compat/app' and 'firebase/compat/firestore'.

Answer (score 5):

I have this working in my project with :

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { CollectionReference, Query } from '@firebase/firestore-types'; // Not usefull for your problem
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
      console.log("firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()");
      console.log(firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
  }
}
```

And in my packages :

```
"firebase": "^4.12.1",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next"
```

I don't have this in packages.json file:

> "@firebase/app"

Comment: Thank you but that didn't help me. At the end, updating the angularfire helped.

Answer (score 0):

I solved of this form:

**importations:** `import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';`

**code:**

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}

private getTimestamp(): Object {
    return this.db.firestore['_firebaseApp'].firebase_.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
  "@angular/fire": "^5.3.0",
  "firebase": "^7.7.0",
```

Answer (score -1):

> Checkout this one

1. Import firestore ## import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
2. get serverTimestamp ## createdAt = firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

[Angular Firestore - serverTimestamp](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/angular/angularfire/1205/565090254)

Answer (score -2):

1. import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

......

......

2. Then try these

- timestamp = firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimeStamp()

or

- timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimeStamp()